# Is there any way to monitor specified AWS service health status such as SES？

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using SES and Mandrill to send my transaction mail, and SES is the default. And I want to monitor whether SES is down so that I can switch my mail service from SES to Mandrill.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the health of an AWS service [here](https://status.aws.amazon.com) .If you want programmatic access then you can use [AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) but it requires a Business or Enterprise support plan from AWS Support as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you could use a Lambda that triggers via cron to curl the AWS status website bdcloud posted above and send a notification via CloudWatch Alerts if the status text indicates an SES error.